How is jiva related to ayusankhara?
Is concept of jiva comparable to the Buddhist notion of āyusaṅkhārā ()? Here is one translation of ayusankhara:

As fast as that man is, as fast as the sun and moon are, and as fast
as the deities that run before the sun and moon are, the waning of the
life forces is faster.

Wiki + Samkhya translation:

Jiva ('a living being') is the state in which Puruṣa is bonded to
Prakriti. Human experience is an interplay of the two, Puruṣa
being conscious of the various combinations of cognitive
activities. The end of the bondage of Puruṣa to Prakriti is called
Moksha (Liberation) or Kaivalya (Isolation).


tamas don’t care, prd

Your question is Is concept of jiva comparable to the Buddhist notion of āyusaṅkhārā?
The Pāl̤i texts use two terms to refer to the energy, or force, or will, that sustains life which are āyusaṅkhāra and jīvitasaṅkhāra. Please bear in mind that energy or force is kārya of Prakriti, so they are Jada (जड/inert) by nature as opposed to Jīva which is consciousness according to the 20th sloka(verse) of Brahmajnānāvalimālā (ब्रह्मज्ञानावलीमाला), written by Shri Ādi Sankarāchāryā:

ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या जीवो ब्रह्मैव नापरः ।
अनेन वेद्यं सच्छास्त्रमिति वेदान्तडिण्डिमः ॥ २०॥.

brahma satyam jaganmithya jīvo brahmaiva nāparah
anena vedyam sacchāstramiti vedāntadindimah ॥ 20 ॥.

Brahman [ब्रह्मन्/The Absolute] is alone real [सत्]; 
the world [जगत्/Jagat] is Mithya [मिथ्या/Illusion];
Ĵiva [जीव] is non-different from Brahman. ॥ 20 ॥


Observe that Ĵiva is non-different from Brahman because both are cethana (चेतना/Conscious Principle).
Conclusion:
Jīva is neither comparable nor related to the Buddhist notion of āyusaṅkhārā because Ĵiva is chaithanyam(चैतन्यम्/consciousness) whereas āyusaṅkhārā is acetana(अचेतन/jaḍa/inert).

Your modification of post quoting Samkhya translation from Wiki saying Jiva ('a living being') is the state in which Puruṣa is bonded to Prakriti. Will you produce the link, please? Thanks.

i guess jada can mean 'dull' or 'inanimate'. jiva can mean 'animate'..

Buddhi/Mind is jada but animated in the presence of chetana principle (Atman). Jiva is non-different from Atman according to Brahmajnānāvalimālā (ब्रह्मज्ञानावलीमाला) by  Shri Ādi Sankarāchāryā. So Jiva too is a chetana principle rather than animate. Let us have an analogy with Fire and a Spark wherein Brahman is Fire and Spark is Ĵiva. Even though Spark is tiny and not as big as Fire, and separated from Fire momentarily, the properties of tiny Spark is one and the same as Fire. Like Fire, the tiny Spark too has light and heat as properties same as Fire.

are you saying the "energy, or force, or will, that sustains life" is acetana? how can that be? life you say is cetana, but the energy that drives life is acetana?

The right context is energy is a kārya of Parkrit, so it is acetana because Prakriti herself is Jada(acetana)! Food sustains our life; water sustains our life. Both Food and water are jada which are kārya of Parkrit,. Everything around us is jada. Our gross body is Jada, subtle body is jada and our causal body is jada. Our Mind, Buddhi, Citta and Ahankara every thing is karya of Prakrit, so they are jada too.

You said in your comment "life you say is cetana, but the energy that drives life is acetana?" Energy is required only to nourish the body and not for Jiva. i.e. Atman does not need nourishment; Atman does not need sleep but our body requires rest. Except Atman everything else is anitya and jada. If there is no nourishment, then the body falls on the ground (aka as death),  and Jiva takes punarjanma (a new embodiment) and this cycle continues until Jiva attains liberation.

Wiki link says (1) Puruṣa is the witness-consciousness (2) Jiva ('a living being') is the state in which Puruṣa is bonded to Prakriti. Sankya Philosophy simply says that Jiva is purusa but attached to Prakrit, therefore Jiva too is a conscious principle. As cetana, Jiva does not need energy but only the body needs it.

if I am not mistaken, Buddha taught cetana to be a function of citta.  therefore, the two systems are incompatible..also, if jiva is purusha, as you say, then the concept of soul is more appropriate than life

Please give me the reference regarding Buddha. Most of the english translations interpret Jiva as soul; Atman(Purusa) to spirit. Please explain what do you mean by life? Thanks.

Here is one of many references...life is what?  idk..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
